# Error installing Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: installation, ubiquity

I'm trying to install UBUNTU 11.10 on my desktop, but it always stops at "configuring the hardware" and will never finish the installation.

Impr Pant: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/521/imprpant.png/

the last line is: --auto --force --quiet

Answer (score 0):

Did you select "upgrade packages while installing" when you installed? If so, try installing without selecting that option. You can run updates after the install if it is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but doesn't work, I had windows 7, my pc was working fine but I wanted to migrate to ubuntu, now does not work. will be some additional configuration I'm missing? maybe in the BIOS?